# SQL "CONTAINS" Searching for partial words

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have a table with over 200,000 rows. And a complex search that involves 4 LEFT OUTER JOINS.

Currently, I **have** to use a CONTAINS function on a full-text indexed table in order to use AND/OR logic to search the content of two different rows.

```
CASE 
        WHEN t1.Contains_Query = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN CONTAINS(query_text.MsWorkSectionContentDraftText, @Keyword) THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END AS 'Contains_Query'
```

Like the above.
However, this is not working for partial keywords.

- N'"general section*"' works
- N'"general*" AND "section*"' works
- N'"general*" OR "section*"' works
- N'"enral*" AND "section*"' does NOT work.

Is there any way, specifically, for CONTAINS to find partial keywords?

Comment: Do you know what the symbol `*` is used for?

Comment: P.S. please tag your database

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz It's supposed to be for prefix searching. According to microsoft, "When <prefix_term> is a phrase, each word contained in the phrase is considered to be a separate prefix". This is what I want. But I do not belive this works as a partial word searcher. Only searches for entire word as prefix to phrase.